# How to get the body of a Response in actix_web unit test?

Tags: rust, actix-web

I'm building a web API service with Rust and actix_web.

I want to test a route and check if the received response body is what I expect. But I'm struggling with converting the received body `ResponseBody<Body>` into JSON or BSON. The called route actually returns `application/json`.

```
let mut app = test::init_service(App::new()
        .data(AppState { database: db.clone() })
        .route("/recipes/{id}", web::post().to(add_one_recipe))
    ).await;

let payload = create_one_recipe().as_document().unwrap().clone();

let req = test::TestRequest::post()
    .set_json(&payload).uri("/recipes/new").to_request();

let mut resp = test::call_service(&mut app, req).await;
let body: ResponseBody<Body> = resp.take_body(); // Here I want the body as Binary, String, JSON, or BSON. The response is actually application/json.
```

Answer (score 9):

The [actix/examples](https://github.com/actix/examples) repository achieves this by defining a new trait called BodyTest...

### Actix Web 3

```rust
trait BodyTest {
    fn as_str(&self) -> &str;
}

impl BodyTest for ResponseBody<Body> {
    fn as_str(&self) -> &str {
        match self {
            ResponseBody::Body(ref b) => match b {
                Body::Bytes(ref by) => std::str::from_utf8(&by).unwrap(),
                _ => panic!(),
            },
            ResponseBody::Other(ref b) => match b {
                Body::Bytes(ref by) => std::str::from_utf8(&by).unwrap(),
                _ => panic!(),
            },
        }
    }
}
```

After which you may simply do:

```
assert_eq!(resp.response().body().as_str(), "Your name is John");
```

### Actix Web 4

This trait is now much simpler (you could skip entirely):

```rust
trait BodyTest {
    fn as_str(&self) -> &str;
}

impl BodyTest for Bytes {
    fn as_str(&self) -> &str {
        std::str::from_utf8(self).unwrap()
    }
}
```

And to use it:

```rust
let body = to_bytes(resp.into_body()).await.unwrap();
assert_eq!(body.as_str(), "Your name is John");
```

Reference to full code these excerpts were taken from: https://github.com/actix/examples/blob/master/forms/form/src/main.rs

Comment: I had to use `resp.response().body().as_str()`.

Answer (score 7):

Having a look at [Body](https://docs.rs/actix-http/1.0.1/src/actix_http/body.rs.html#581) and ResponseBody, this looks like the approach:

```rust
use actix_web::{web, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer, Responder};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Greet {
    name: String,
}

async fn greet() -> impl Responder {
    let body = serde_json::to_string(&Greet {
        name: "Test".to_owned(),
    })
    .unwrap();
    HttpResponse::Ok()
        .content_type("application/json")
        .body(body)
}

#[actix_rt::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(|| App::new().route("/", web::get().to(greet)))
        .bind("127.0.0.1:8000")?
        .run()
        .await
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use actix_web::{body::Body, test, web, App};
    use serde_json::json;

    #[actix_rt::test]
    async fn test_greet_get() {
        let mut app = test::init_service(App::new().route("/", web::get().to(greet))).await;
        let req = test::TestRequest::with_header("content-type", "application/json").to_request();
        let mut resp = test::call_service(&mut app, req).await;
        let body = resp.take_body();
        let body = body.as_ref().unwrap();
        assert!(resp.status().is_success());
        assert_eq!(
            &Body::from(json!({"name":"Test"})), // or serde.....
            body
        );
    }
}
```

```sh
running 1 test
test tests::test_greet_get ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for testing in one go, the body and status code :

```rust
let req = test::TestRequest::get()
    .uri(&format!("/brand/{}", 999))
    .to_request();
let resp = test::call_service(&mut app, req).await;
assert_eq!(resp.status(), StatusCode::NOT_FOUND);
let body = test::read_body(resp).await;
assert_eq!(actix_web::web::Bytes::from("Item not found"), body);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#[actix_rt::test]
pub async fn test_index() {
    let mut app = test::init_service(App::new().service(ping)).await;
    let req = test::TestRequest::get().uri("/ping").to_request();
    let result = test::read_response(&mut app, req).await;
    assert_eq!(result, Bytes::from_static(b"PONG"));
}
```

Please see the [doc](https://docs.rs/actix-web/3.3.2/actix_web/test/fn.read_response.html)